# Celery 3.0.12 countdown not working

Tags: python, celery

When I run my task: `my_task.apply_async([283], countdown=5)` It runs immediately when it should be running 5 seconds later as the ETA says

[2013-01-08 15:15:21,600: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: web.my_task[4635f997-6232-4722-9a99-d1b42ccd5ab6] eta:[2013-01-08 15:20:51.580994]
[2013-01-08 15:15:22,095: INFO/MainProcess] Task web.my_task[4635f997-6232-4722-9a99-d1b42ccd5ab6] succeeded in 0.494245052338s: None

here is my installation:

software -> celery:3.0.12 (Chiastic Slide) kombu:2.5.4 py:2.7.3
billiard:2.7.3.19 py-amqp: N/A
platform -> system:Darwin arch:64bit imp:CPython
loader -> djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader
settings -> transport:amqp results:mongodb

Is this a celery bug? or I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in celery 3.0.12, reverting to celery 3.0.11 did the job.

Hope this helps someone